# Synthetic transmission fluid for a Peugeot 508 1.6 turbo petrol?

Tags: automatic-transmission, peugeot

My car has Aisin gear box AM6 recommended AW1 Oil (it's mineral oil).

I need to know 2 things:

1. Is it possible to change to synthetic oil?
2. As this oil is not aftermarket yet, what equivalent oils could be recommended?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The above is not quite correct.  AW-1 must be used in vehicles with am AM6 gearbox that are Euro 5 approved (from 2010).  You must NOT put JWS339 oil into a later AM6 gearbox.  It specifically states this in the Official Citroen service documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm reading, there's no Peugeot *approved* synthetic alternative to the AW1 Oil. You can replace the AW1 with Mobil ATF 3309 which is a lot cheaper than the AW1 Oil you'd purchase at the dealership. It is compatible with the AM6 (AWTF-80) transmission. The Mobil ATF 3309 fluid is NOT synthetic.

While not *approved* by Peugeot, I've read on [internet forums](https://www.bobistheoilguy.com/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=1163321) people are using Amsoil ATF or Redline D4 ATF. Both of these are synthetic ATF fluids and it seems the people on there are having good results with them. They are stating the shifts are greatly improved over the ATF fluids which are JWS 3309 compliant.

Bottom line is, people (quite a few, in fact) are using these synthetics with great success, but with all things, if you switch over to it, you do it at your own risk. If you are out of warranty, there probably isn't anything to worry about. Also, while the AW1 Oil is said to be "for life" from the factory, it's not a bad thing to change it out on a regular basis. Nothing wrong with clean transmission fluid. **I'll throw one great big huge caveat on that statement:** If your vehicle has high mileage you may not want to change the oil. It's been said changing out high mileage oil can cause all the gunk which is holding the transmission together to come free and cause issues, which might necessitate a new transmission. This statement does come under dispute, so take it for what it's worth.